# Creating executable for Qt projects

Tags: linux, windows, qt

I have a Qt application that run on Linux. I want to have its executable such that it can operate on Windows too without Qt being installed. I have seen the older posts too regarding this but couldn't understand them. Please guide me step by step to create executable file.
I have placed all the necessary dlls alongside and was successful to run the executable. But to run it I need to go inside the folder and than do that.

How can I wrap my application, such that user has the set up for that, he installs it and then run that (usually we have for the S/ws). How can I do this for the Qt application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the setup for Qt for Windows with MinGW compiler [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

Once you install Qt IDE on a Windows machine, make necessary changes to your project's .pro file and build your application.

Now copy the executable you created into a different folder and run a dependency check on it. You can use Dependency Walker which you can download from [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Copy the dlls shown in the Dependency walker and place it next to your application. You will find the required dlls in the Qt's bin folder in the installation directory. Path might be something like C:\Qt\Qt\\mingw\bin. You will also need to copy the gcc and mingw dlls into your application directory.

Next you will have to copy the required `plugins` into your application directory. You will need the `platforms` plugins, `iconengines` and `imageformats` if you are using icons, `sqldrivers` if your application connects to a database. Copy the directories of the required plugins into your application folder.

Once you copy all required libraries, you should be able to open the application. You can now distribute your application along with all these dynamic link libraries and plugins.

For more details you can refer this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies).

Comment: I have added qwindows.dll too still it gives me the eror: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows". What is to be done.

Comment: Have you copied the directory named platforms to your app directory? You will find it in the plugins directory.

Comment: Yes, I have copied whole of the directory. In my directory I have executable, Qtdlls and platforms directory in it.

Answer (score 1):

You should place Qt DLLs along the release version of your executable. These are `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Gui.dll`, `Qt5Widgets.dll` and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These dll files are in your installed Qt Directory in `bin` folder.

You should also place `msvcr100.dll` and `msvcp100.dll` in case you are using MSVS2010.
If you are using MinGW, place `MINGWM10.DLL`, `LIBGCC_S_DW2-1.dll` and `LIBSTDC++-6.dll` alongside the executable.

If you are using plugins you should place their dll in a folder named `plugins` beside your exe. In case of using icons and images you should ship their dlls like `qico.dll` and `qsvg.dll` in a folder named `imageformats`.

You should also put `qwindows.dll` in a folder named `platforms` alongside the executable.

Comment: I am using mingw compiler.

Comment: I have installed Qt on Windows and in the release verion I found the executable, copied the executables required dlls in one folder and ran the executable, it was successfull. But when I copied the folder and ran the executable on other system with no Qt installed, it gave me an error " This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows". What is to be done.

Comment: @user3877872 You should also put qwindows.dll in a folder named platforms alongside the executable. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It worked out but do we have any other procedure so that user need to go inside the folder, he must click on the icon and we can serve our application.